# PP_E_RPS_CERT_NOT_FOUND error when querying Outlook API

Tags: php, api, outlook, calendar

I am trying to retrieve the contents of my calendar using the Outlook REST API, but I am getting weird error responses.

The code is based on the example code supplied by Microsoft in https://github.com/microsoftgraph/php-connect-rest-sample

I have created an application and specified it want access to `calendar.read` and changed the scope in the testcode, `Constants::SCOPE`, to include this scope.

After succesfully retrieving a token I can verify that the application requests and sets the correct privileges. After that I try to retrieve the events in my calendar as described at the documentation: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/api/calendar-rest-operations#get-series-master-and-single-events-rest

I use the Advanced REST client add-on for Chrome to create a GET request with the following specs:

Url: `https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/me/events`
Headers:

`Authorization: Bearer [token]
Prefer: outlook.timezone=Europe/Berlin`

The response I get is a 401 status code with the following content for the `X-Ms-Diagnostics` header:

`2000010;reason="ErrorCode: 'PP_E_RPS_CERT_NOT_FOUND'. Message: 'Certificate cannot be found. Certificate required for the operation cannot be found.%0d%0a Internal error: spRPSTicket->ProcessToken failed. Failed to call CRPSDataCryptImpl::UnpackData:Certificate cannot be found. Certificate required for the operation cannot be found.%0d%0a Internal error: Failed to decrypt data. :Failed to get session key. RecipientId=293577. spCache->GetCacheItem returns error.:Cert Name: (null). SKI: d6c3dacffd2b3fba2fb3d6c2b0fcd78680a3acd1...'";error_category="invalid_msa_ticket"`

The `Www-Authenticate` header specifies 'error="invalid_token"' while the token was just received.

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Any luck with this issue?

Comment: No, and since I've moved to another job I am no longer investigating this issue. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

I think another thing you might be able to check out is the scope when you request the v2 endpoint. for V2 endpoint, the scope is different between Graph API and outlook api. you need to specify scope as "https://outlook.office.com/calendars.read" instead of Graph scope. 
I hope it will help.

Comment: This helped, Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to just change the URL from https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/me/events to https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/events

Answer (score 0):

Basically, the message means that the **token** you're trying to use is not valid for the operation.

I went through this. This is how I've solved:

1. I use the suggested scopes here (I was creating an event): https://msdn.microsoft.com/office/office365/APi/calendar-rest-operations#create-events
2. To get the authorization code I used this URL schema:
   https://login.live.com/oauth20_authorize.srf?client_id=[YourClientID]&scope=[ScopeYouNeed]&response_type=code&redirect_uri=[YourRedirectURI]

Then I get the refresh & the access token. And now it's working!

Comment: The error continues to show up. *BUT* I did notice something; I don't have an office 365 account, but an ordinary Outlook (@hotmail) account. I was under the assumption that the calendar I have access to is the also accessible via this API. Could it be that only the Office 365 calendars are callable via this API?

Comment: Yes, in the case of outllok accounts I used this Url to get the authorization code: `https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id={clientId}&response_type=code&redirect_uri={YourRedirectURI}&scope={YourScope}&response_mode=query&nonce={aRandomId}&state=abcd`

Comment: @Rod - I am getting the same error for my hotmail account even though I used the exact same Url you mentioned. I am able to get the access code through a Post to this url and even the access token is issued, but the subscription endpoint is giving me the exact same response.